# UIPickerView to View controller

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview, viewcontroller

How do I get a UIPickerView choice to direct me to a view controller? I want every choice to lead me to a different view controller. I was thinking about making a button but I don't know how I'd have that once button control all 3 choices.

Comment: what code do you have? is it calling you back and telling you which option was selected?

Comment: you can use a variable to store value when you choose some UIPIckerView choice and after that inside button click you can use that variable value to decide where to go ( which view controller).   Use if to decide that or switch statements. http://www.dotnetperls.com/switch-swift

Answer (score 1):

When a user picks something on the pickerView, you can implement `func pickerView (_didSelectRow)` and add functionality based on the indexRow or selection they picked. Here is a good example of that in a tutorial: [UIPickerView Example](http://sourcefreeze.com/ios-uipickerview-example-using-swift/)

I think a better way would be to add a button once they have chosen the picker selection. You can create an `@IBAction func pickerButtonPressed`, or whatever you wish to name the action, and make an if else statement with `prepareForSegue` that is based on the indexRow selection of the pickerView that is used when they press the button.

Answer (score 0):

A UIPickerView sends the following event to it's delegates:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
```

Put your code in there to determine which cell was picked and then launch a segue to the view you would like to load.